# Can I use Context().Done() to check server shutdown?

Tags: go

As golang `http` package document saying, `http.Server` will not close until all handler finished after `Shutdown()` called. If handler take too long time, context will expires, and `Shutdown()` returns a error. What should I do for forcing handler to return immediately when `server.Shutdown()` has been called? Will `Context().Done()` of `http.Request` be closed after `server.ShutDown()` has been called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you [read the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Shutdown), it explains exactly what `Shutdown` does, saying explicitly that it does *not* interrupt active connections (emphasis added):

> Shutdown gracefully shuts down the server **without interrupting any active connections**. Shutdown works by first closing all open listeners, then closing all idle connections, and then waiting indefinitely for connections to return to idle and then shut down. If the provided context expires before the shutdown is complete, Shutdown returns the context's error, otherwise it returns any error returned from closing the Server's underlying Listener(s).